# integrate sound and clignote evenement on button

Tags: javascript, css

I work with extjs 3.4 .

using css and javascript I want to show and hide the button,

make a flashing button and add sound on this button when the button appeared

I have this code :

```
<li>


<div id="mydiv" style="display: none"><input id="bouton1" class="buttonNotif" onclick="testURL('/group/test')" type="submit" value="" /></div>

        </li>
```

this is my css code in order to make a flashing button

```
.buttonNotif{
    background: transparent url(../images/custom/mail.png) no-repeat !important;
    height: 25px;
    width: 30px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #4183C4;
    -webkit-animation-name: clignote; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite; 
}
```

and I used this code in javascript :

```
var result =getResult();
if(result)
                    {
                    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'block';

                    }
                else
                    {
                    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'none';
                    }
```

with this code the button will show and hide according to  condition
but  **the button does not flash**

I try also without success to use javascript code  :

```
 var result =getResult();
     if(result)
                            {
                            document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'block';

    clignoterBouton('bouton1');
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'none';
                            }


        function clignoterBouton(idDuBouton) {
                var clignotementsAvantArret = 10;  // NOMBRE DE CLIGNOTEMENTS AVANT L'ARRET
                // DES CLIGNOTEMENTS. METTRE UNE LETTRE
                // POUR QUE LE CLIGNOTEMENT NE S'ARRETE PAS

                var vitesseDeClignotement = 5;     // VITESSE DE CLIGNOTEMENT.
                        // MIN = 1, MAX = 10
                var compte = 0;
                var charge = 0;
                if(charge == 0) {
                document.getElementById(idDuBouton).style.visibility = "hidden";
                charge = 1;
                compte++;
                if(compte != clignotementsAvantArret) {
                setTimeout("clignoterBouton('"+idDuBouton+"')",(10-vitesseDeClignotement)*100);
                }
                else {
                document.getElementById(idDuBouton).style.visibility = "visible";
                }
                } else if(charge == 1) {

                document.getElementById(idDuBouton).style.visibility = "visible";
                charge = 0;
                if(compte != clignotementsAvantArret) {
                setTimeout("clignoterBouton('"+idDuBouton+"')",(10-vitesseDeClignotement)*100);
                } else {
                document.getElementById(idDuBouton).style.visibility = "visible";
                }
                }
                }
```

**for the event sound I fail to integrate into my button**

```
  var result =getResult();
         if(result)
                                {
                                document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'block';

        clignoterBouton('bouton1');

// call sound function
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'none';
                                }
```